# jquery auto refresh without blinking

Tags: jquery, refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = setupRefresh;

function setupRefresh() {
  setTimeout("refreshPage();", 1000);
}
function refreshPage() {
   window.location = location.href;
}
```

The page is now reloading every second the only problem its blinking how to fix this

Comment: you need to use ajax and apply the content directly in dom

Comment: It looks like it does what it's supposed to no? Why do you want to reload the page every second??

Comment: of course it will blink.. the page needs to reload and that requires a bit of time. Also no need to do what you are doing with javascript, just use a `meta` tag

Comment: it needs to be updated every second to check for new content

Comment: don't refresh the entire page each second, but a part of it, or users will get crazy. Use asynchronous request to get update from server. See my answer too, and look for AJAX.

Comment: it's a page thats only visible from a beamer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use a div and a .get with jquery to get your data from another page on your website.

You can use setTimeOut(function, time)

```
$(function() {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
    $.get('pagelink.php', function(data) {
        $('#content_div_id').html(data);    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If the page is completely reloading and overwriting itself (including the script that is doing the reloading, then try this version:

```
function startRefresh() {
    $.get('', function(data) {
        $(document.body).html(data);    
    });
}
$(function() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't reload a page that way without the blink effect. Have a look at AJAX to fetch updated content of the page and display it asynchronously in the "existing" page.

Have a look at: http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/jquery-auto-refresh-div-every-x-seconds/, to refresh part of the screen (the part can be the unique `<DIV>` of the page).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for answer with function, but if I want use about 1 minute delay, I must start calling of function with the delay by this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var vTimeOut;

$(function() {
  vTimeOut= setTimeout(startRefresh, 60000)
});


function startRefresh() {
  clearInterval(vTimeOut);
  vTimeOut= setTimeout(startRefresh, 60000);
  $(<#div>).load(<loadURL>);
}

//]]>
</script>
```

Otherwise, the startRefresh functions fire very quickly or repeated more times.